# Google Maps - Places library - Search for custom placed markers in radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a app that makes use of the Gmaps Places library and actually, I have two questions:

1) Does anyone know how long it takes to an added place(by POST request) to show up on the map? I only need it on the app's map, so I don't care if Google doesn't approve it. I've already sent the add request and received OK as response.

2) It is possible to search for markers, placed by me, as if they were places(and using radius)? Not necessarily using the Places library. I ask this to see if is possible to come with a backup plan if the waiting mentioned above is long(clients, clients...). Then I would have the places 'offline from Gmaps', mapped inside a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to combine Google's Places API with a custom location set?  Without more detail I can't really tell you what the code would look like, but you'd basically want to mash up the results you get from places with your own data and place markers based on that merge.  If you're searching by radius or polygon you can do a 'within bounds' search on your dataset and return any results that are within the search zone to feed into your marker creator.